# Linux cannot locate Gemfile or .bundle/directory even though it is/should be there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, git, backup

I am backing up gitlab from a server after [this script](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md). I have to type in:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

The outcome of it is:

```
Could not locate `Gemfile` or `.bundle/` directory
```

Am I doing something wrong here? If I search with the `find` command after `Gemfile`, Linux finds it, but if I use the `locate` command it doesn't. Does that mean there may be my error?

Comment: Change directory to that, returned by `find` command: `cd DIRECTORY_OF_GEMFILE` before executing `bundle`.

Comment: did you install from source or with ominbus?

Comment: I installed it from source